# Asymmetric uncertainty propagation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astrophysics, astronomy, error-analysis, statistics

I am trying to calculate planet-star mass ratios for a number of observed systems, i.e. $\mu=\frac{m_{planet}}{M_{star}}$. Now, most of the planet masses come with asymmetric errors, e.g. WASP 10 system: $m_{star}=.902^{+.04}_{-.038} M_{Sol}\ \    m_{p}=.885^{+.374}_{-.343} M_{Jup}$,  where $M_{Jup}=1.89813e27\ kg$ and $M_{Sol}=1.9886e30\ kg$. I have tried adding the separate uncertainties in quadrature as $\delta\mu_\pm=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial m}\delta m_\pm\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial M}\delta M_\pm\right)^2}$, but I am not sure this is the right way to do it. If anyone has experience with such calculations, I'd very much appreciate your advice. Cheers.

Comment: You can always use a random number generator to Monte Carlo it (maybe with suitable log-normal distributions)--though those you quoted are barely asymmetric.